# How to compare two json object, check if id is same then assign to another object value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have two objects

```
var JSON_Categories = '[{ "id" : "1", "text" : "Category A"}, { "id" : 2, "text" : "Category B" }]';
var JSON_Article = '[{ "id" : "1", "text" : "Article text A"}, { "id" : 3, "text" : "Article B"}]';
var categories = JSON.parse(JSON_Categories);
var article = JSON.parse(JSON_Article);
```

if id match for both JSON value then, I need to assign text category text value with an article text value.

it tried something like this, I know it's not a good solution can anyone help me on it?

```
var categoryValue = new Object();
categories.forEach(function(category) {
articles.forEach(article => {
    if (category.id === article.id) {
        categoryValue.id = category.id;
        categoryValue.text = article.text;
    } else {
        categoryValue.id = category.id;
        categoryValue.text = category.text;
    }
});
});

console.log('categoryValue', categoryValue);
```

Comment: do you want to replace every matching object in `categories` or just one?

Comment: also, do you want to replace the values in the original array or create a new array with the modified objects?

Comment: only one text  value, but I need to compete for the object after replacing text value, one value.

Comment: That's not a JSON problem. Yes, `JSON_Categories` and `JSON_Article` contain JSON, but you're not doing anything with them besides parsing. The actual comparison is the question/problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` it and inside that `find` the Object from second array:

```js
var JSON_Categories = JSON.parse('[{ "id" : "1", "text" : "Category A"}, { "id" : 2, "text" : "Category B" }]');
var JSON_Article = JSON.parse('[{ "id" : "1", "text" : "Article text A"}, { "id" : 3, "text" : "Article B"}]');

var result = JSON_Categories.map(({id, text})=>({id, text:JSON_Article.find(k=>k.id==id)?.text || text}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's working perfectly with js example, but when using with same with Angular 8, getting an error ":" expected, how I can use the same with Angular?

Comment: @YOG_PHP seems you are getting `type` error, try to specify type like this `JSON_Categories.map(({id, text}:any)`

Comment: (k=>k.id==id)?.text, its showing error in this place.